# Scattering matrix in time domain, causality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, causality, time-evolution, s-matrix-theory, quantum-transport

In this question, I consider scattering problems in one dimension. In the scattering matrix formulation in quantum mechanics, the scattering outgoing (out) waves can be written as, $$\psi^{(out)}(E)=\sum_{\beta}b_\beta \frac{1}{\sqrt{\hbar v_\beta}}\psi^{(out)}_\beta(E)=\sum_{\beta,\gamma}S_{\beta\gamma}(E)a_\gamma \frac{1}{\sqrt{\hbar v_\beta}}\psi^{(out)}_\beta(E),$$
where $\psi^{(out)}_\beta$ are the basis functions (consider outgoing plane waves), and $v_\beta$ are the corresponding group velocities, which we can approximate as energy independent. $S_{\beta\gamma}$ is the S-matrix, relating the coefficients $b_\beta$ in the outgoing waves to their counterparts $a_\gamma$ in the incoming wave. Note that I am not referring to the wave-vectors as they can be traded in for the energy by using the dispersion relation $E\sim k^2$.
Now, in time-domain,
$$\psi^{(out)}(t)=\int\frac{dE}{2\pi}e^{-iEt}\psi^{(out)}_\beta(E)=\sum_{\beta\gamma}\frac{a_\gamma}{\sqrt{\hbar v_\beta}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau S_{\beta\gamma}(t-\tau)\psi^{(out)}_\beta(\tau).$$
Clearly, for ensuring causality, $S_{\beta\gamma}(t-\tau)=\int (dE/2\pi)S_{\beta\gamma}(E)e^{-iEt}\sim\Theta(t-\tau)$ where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function. Typically the S-matrix is obtained by solving the Schroedinger's equation and matching the incoming and outgoing wavefunctions suitably. Starting from the energy domain scattering matrix, can this requirement be proven generally for any scattering potential? That is, can we show that the causality requirement, as evident from the time-domain form of the S-matrix ($\sim\Theta(t-\tau)$), follows naturally from the corresponding energy domain expression for any potential?

EDIT: Following the document at https://www.physics.purdue.edu/webapps/index.php/course_document/index/phys661/1694/25/14268
with the field-theoretic S-matrix given by (56), it seems in a perturbative calculation, since the poles of the constituent resolvents making up the S-matrix are in the lower-half plane, causality is guaranteed. However, this argument does not seem to readily extend to the full non-perturbative S-matrix, which is required to obtain bound states.